# Icon in applications folder is a folder full of files

Tags: applications

I noticed that one of the applications in the Launchpad (/Applications folder) is a folder with a bunch of files in it.

Have two questions:

1) How does OS X actually launch the program

2) Which of the files in that folder is actually the application

When opening the folder in `Terminal` it comes up as `Chromium.app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called an [Application Bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)#macOS_application_bundles).  Within the application bundle is a hierarchy of files as follows:

```
Chromium App
  Contents
    MacOS
       Chromium
```

macOS launches the file by calling the file located in `Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium`.  It knows to execute this file becuase....well...after all, it's Apple's framework.  macOS knows that the executable will be located here.

If you wanted to lauch the file manually (like in Terminal), you could just issue the command

```
/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
```

Comment: While the executable is normally in `name.app/Contents/MacOS/`, nonetheless the OS knows what to execute because it's registered in the **Launch Services Database**, not just because its path happens to be `name.app/Contents/MacOS/`, as there can be more then one executable at that location. The name of the executable is also usually defined in the `name.app/Contents/info.plist` file.